# С чего начать создание игры с изометрическим видом в canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5

В общем, нужно создать игру, две недели провел в поисках фреймворка, все впустую. (

Подскажите, где искать, с чего начать.

Comment: критерии поиска недостаточные для советов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO

Этот "убийца флеша" со своими ~20 низкоуровневыми функциями, кучей сырых полуюзабельных фреймворков в разработке и отсутствием хороших туториалов не очень-то подходит для написания игр, если человек не является профессионалом в этой самой разработке игр. Но можете посмотреть на canvasengine, processingjs,  KineticJS, Raphael, fabric.js, и может, что-то приглянется. А так только низкоуровневый кодинг.